# Does Django allow up to two HttpResponseRedirects between views

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views

I'm wondering if it's possible to HttpResponseRedirect from view1 to view2 and finally to view3.

Psuedo code for views:

```
class view1:
 HttpResponseRedirect(reverse-url-for-view2)

class view2:
 HttpResponseRedirect(reverse-url-for-view3)

class view3:
 #I want to end up here and maybe return a 200
```

Is this possible please and if not how can I do this. I'm currently able to redirect to view2 but not from view2 to view3.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really want to redirect them or have them call common functions?

Comment: _"I'm currently able to redirect to view2 but not from view2 to view3"_
what happens?  do you get an error?

Comment: Have you checked your urls.py? I think you might not define your view3's path.

Comment: I get something like this: `AssertionError: 302 != 200 : Couldn't retrieve redirection page 'reverse-url-for-view2': response code was 302 (expected 200)`

Comment: Yeah, it's defined.

Comment: Happy to either redirect or call common functions. I think either route will solve my problems.

Comment: You have asked the [same question already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71919799/assertionerror-302-200-couldnt-retrieve-redirection-page-api-v2-app-nex) - please don't ask multiple times. Also note that what is failing is your *testing* of the views, not the views themselves.

Comment: I'm sorry about that. Do you mind explaining in the main post how to test it correctly. I can add my test there. Thanks

Comment: Please add your test code to the original question

Comment: Added. Thank you.